# testcase failed when getting variable output from bot using botium box

Tags: chatbot

I am using botium-box. I have the following convo file:

[image: text]

Here the date is a variable and changes everyday so I have to change it everyday in convo file otherwise the testcase is failing.

I have tried few solutions:

1. setting `SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY` to true in advance settings and using 
   placeholder for variables. For eg.

[image: text with SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY]

2. I tried setting `INTENT_CONFIDENCE` to 70 in advance settings and using 
   in convo file. For eg:

[image: text with INTENT_CONFIDENCE]

3. I tried `INTENT_CONFIDENCE` directly in convo file without setting it in advance capabilities. For eg.

[image: text with INTENT_CONFIDENCE 70]

4. I tried using `%s` in place of variable. For eg.

[image: text with %s placeholder]

Testcases are still failing. Is it a bug? Do I have to change any Botium settings? How can I do partial matching of responses?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 should be working (see [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Scripting#scripting-memory) and [here](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-2-writing-chatbot-tests-8726204c8da6)). If it doesn't work, please attach log file for analysis.
Options 2 and 3 are for something totally different (verification of intent resolution confidence), and Option 4 is not a Botium feature.

What you can try as well: Botium by default does substring matching for assertions, so your convo file could look something like this:

```
#me
what is the date today ?

#bot
Today is
```